Circular references with MAP and SCAN embedded functions
.I have created a formula where i want to calculate the depreciation expenses dynamically using MAP function for depreciating the asset with certain conditions and SCAN to calculate dynamically cumulative sums. E19:AF19 are the years depreciating, $F$20:$AF$20 are the additions of capex every year, C21 is the year(in the photo this is a format and it is only the year), E12 is the rate of depreciation and E21:AF21 is the array i want to use for calculating the depreciation based on the excel Spreadsheet .My current function is below and there is circular reference:
=MAP(E21:AF21;
    SCAN(0; E21:AF21; LAMBDA(acc;curr; acc + curr));
        LAMBDA(curr;sumSoFar;IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(19; COLUMN(curr))) > $C21;sumSoFar < INDEX($F$20:$AF$20; MATCH($C21; $F$19:$AF$19; 0))); INDEX($F$20:$AF$20; MATCH($C21; $F$19:$AF$19; 0)) * $E$12; 0)))

I tried the function above, but it returned a circular reference, what i expect is a dynamic array of depreciation expenses, the formula i want to imitate is.
=IF(AND(G$19>$C21;SUM($E21:F21)<HLOOKUP($C21;$F$19:$AF$20;2;FALSE));HLOOKUP($C21;$F$19:$AF$20;2;FALSE)*$E$12;0)


MAP input should be a range or array or multiple ranges /arrays used to calculate a result the same size as the input size. You can't refer to it's own outcome within the calculation. If you can't to do that, you need REDUCE, but in this case it's a simple wrong syntax referencing the range that will be the output of the formula as an input. If you post your data as data (markdown table) and explain what logic you need, I'm sure we can translate it to a formula.

I thought this would be the case. I want to avoid self-reference as i want to have a calculator of the accumulated depreciation inside the let function.  Thank you for the reply.

To be clear what i want is to calculate depreciation of new capex every year based on a rate and i want my total depreciation to not exceed the initial capex.

Your formula for F21 is:
=IF(F19:Q19>C21:C32;D21:D32*$E$12;"-")



How can I understand, the accumulated depreciation is just a sum of year-by-year depreciations:

You need to enter F33 the formula =SUM(F21:F32) and fill it to right.

If you need the accumulated depreciation only,

Use the next formula:
[E22] =SCAN(0,D21:D32*$E$12,LAMBDA(a,i,a+i))


Thank you for the reply. The calculation of the depreciation is right. What i want is the calculation of the accumulated depreciation, in order to not exceed the addition of capex( I am calculating depreciation of new capex).

Also pls. provide verbal formula to calculate of the accumulated depreciation, I'll make the solution.

Updated 2024-09-26
=LET(
    depr_pct, E12,
    life, $D$12,
    years, F19:Q19,
    additions, F20:Q20,
    yr_rows, C21:C30,
    depr_amt, additions * depr_pct,
    cumulative_addtions, LAMBDA(yr, SUMPRODUCT(additions * (years <= yr))),
    cumulative_depr, LAMBDA(yr, SUMPRODUCT(depr_amt * (years <= yr))),
    net_value, LAMBDA(yr, cumulative_addtions(yr) - cumulative_depr(yr)),
    adj_depr_amt, LAMBDA(r, c,
        LET(
            yr_col, INDEX(years, 1, c),
            yr_row, INDEX(yr_rows, r, 1),
            IFS(
                yr_col <= yr_row,
                0,
                yr_col > MIN(years) + life,
                0,
                net_value(yr_col) >= 0,
                XLOOKUP(yr_row, years, depr_amt),
                net_value(yr_col) + XLOOKUP(yr_col, years, depr_amt) > 0,
                net_value(yr_col) + XLOOKUP(yr_col, years, depr_amt),
                TRUE,
                0
            )
        )
    ),
    MAKEARRAY(ROWS(yr_rows), COLUMNS(years), adj_depr_amt)
)



ver 1
Since, non-lambda version seems to be favorable:)
=LET(
    depr_percent, E12,
    yc, F19:Q19,
    yr, C21:C30,
    addition_for_year, XLOOKUP(yr, F19:Q19, F20:Q20, 0),
    IF(yc <= yr, "", depr_percent * addition_for_year)
)



Thank you for the reply. I used the formula as is and the only element missing is stopping the depreciation when exceeding useful life( lets assume useful life is 0)

@csuitedealer, I've added a suggestion to handle this. Please see whether the logic is what you wanted and whether it works with your data. I don't have much time to test it today.

I think this is what you're after:
=DROP(REDUCE(0,F20:S20,LAMBDA(x,y,IFNA(HSTACK(x,VSTACK(TAKE(x,,-1),y*E12)),0))),1)

Or if you want the zeros as true - =DROP(REDUCE(0,F20:S20,LAMBDA(x,y,IFNA(HSTACK(x,VSTACK(TAKE(x,,-1),IF(y,y*E12,"-"))),"-"))),1)

Thank you. This is the outcome that i expected. the only element missing in the formula is stopping when accumulated depreciation is the same with the addition of capital expenditure

Can you add an example?
